# ios- create multiple window app

Tags: ios, iphone, multi-window

How to create an application to support multiple windows.
So that user can create new or close window simultaneously in the same app like we can see in browsers.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: down-voters can leave comment....

Comment: All iOS apps are essentially one window only. What you're referring to is a view which displays other views within it.

Comment: Do you want to make app like safari browser ?

Comment: Use the UIpageController add Views as Windows and do accordingly with the delegates .

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper: ri8..I am looking for same or you can see `SkyScanner`

Comment: @KumarKl: thanks for the idea...any references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use multiple windows. The app could have multiple windows but this wouldn't give you the effect you want (or would be an abusive way of creating it).

Instead, what you want is a container view controller which manages, in a custom way, a number of child view controllers. Think about how a tab view controller works - you want the same thing, just presented in a different way.

Taks a look at [HGPageScrollView](https://github.com/100grams/HGPageScrollView) for inspiration and reuse.

Comment: This is true. I would also like to add, that by using native view animations you can animate views as you like before removing them (if user wants to remove them) and also use animations when user adds something. This way it will look just like any modern browser (from user perspective).

Comment: how to save the changes? is it using `Saving application state`?

Comment: Save which changes? Creating new 'windows' and removing them? You could use user defaults to store the list of configuration details for each one...

Answer (score 2):

as of `iOS13` and `XCode11` you can create multiple window apps for iPad OS by setting the `Enable Multiple Windows` property in `info.plist` to `YES`.